# C++: return a std::vector<> member, by reference, to a temporary object

Tags: c++, memory-management, pass-by-reference, stdvector, temporary-objects

I have two functions.

function1 calls function2, which returns a reference to an object, that I then use to call a public function.

```
function1(function2).returned_object.mymethod();
```

This is a fairly unwieldy way to do things, but it works.

Now I have a problem where I need to call one method, then another method, so I need a temporary object.

```
ClassName temp_obj = function1(function2);

temp_obj.method1();
temp_obj.method2();
```

My question is, how can I declare a temporary object that will store the object that returns by reference. I'm guessing I need a pointer.

The other problem is, temp_obj is contained in a vector, and I'm concerned about conflicts there and memory leakage. If I use a pointer, will I then have to use a destructor also?

Here is the relevant code:

```
bool Machine::perform_function(std::vector<Job>& jobs) {
    bool add = true;

    if (can_fail) {
        add = coin_toss();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < my_jobs.size(); i++) {

        if (add) {
            find_job(my_jobs[i], jobs).toggle(name, item_name, true);

        }
        if (!add) {
            find_job(my_jobs[i], jobs).toggle(name, item_name, false);

        }
    }

    return add;
}


Job& Machine::find_job(std::string jobname, std::vector<Job>& jobs) {

    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) {

        if (jobs[i].is_job(jobname)) {
            return jobs[i];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "how can I declare a temporary object that will store the function that returns by reference" - you can't store a function in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to store the result as a reference:

```
ClassName & temp_obj = function1(function2);
temp_obj.method1();
temp_obj.method2();
```

Your other question here:

> The other problem is, temp_obj is contained in a vector, and I'm concerned about conflicts there and memory leakage.

It's okay to return `jobs[i]` as a reference.  The `operator[]` on a vector returns a reference itself.  Provided you don't modify the vector in such a way as to change what that reference points at, and you are not storing a reference to an object that has been destroyed, you'll be fine to use it.

When your temporary reference goes out of scope, nothing happens.  It's just a reference.

Comment: What happens when the reference goes out of scope?

Comment: @bigcodeszzer: nothing, a reference doesn't own an object nor it can cause a leak, it's just an alias for an existing object.

Answer (score 2):

You need a temporary variable, but that temporary variable could be a reference so no copy is done and you are safe to use it.

But still better, you could use `<algorithm>` functions to do what you need without having to reinvent the wheel:

```
std::string name = ...;
auto it = std::find_if(begin(jobs), end(jobs), [&name] (const Job& job) { return job.is_job(name); });

if (it != jobs.end())
{
  it->method1();
  it->method2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is `function1()` that returns a reference (your question is unclear on that), simply use a reference

```
 ClassName &temp_obj = function1(function2);

 temp_obj.method1();
 temp_obj.method2();
```

If `function1()` returns a `const` reference, than `temp` also needs to be `const`.

The limitation of this is that, once created, a reference cannot be reseated (made to refer to a different object).  For example, in ;

```
 ClassName &temp_obj = function1(function2);    // initialisation

 temp_obj = function1(some_other_function);     // reassignment
 temp_obj.method1();
 temp_obj.method2();
```

the reassignment will not reseat `temp`, even if `function1()` returns a different reference on the second call.   Instead, the object being referred to will be assigned (assuming it has a working assignment operator).     If you want a variable that can refer to different objects over time, you need a pointer.

```
 ClassName *temp_obj = &function1(function2);    // assumes function1() returns a reference

 temp_obj = &function1(some_other_function);      //  reassigns the pointer

 temp_obj->method1();
 temp_obj->method2();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear. But if you want to make a pointer to a function or member function there is a FAQ about such variables here.

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types